# AWT & Swing problems

Tags: java, swing, awt, textfield

[image]

Can anybody say to me, why it can appear?
When Thread is working, it happens.

Comment: I agree, but AWT_TextField have method ValueChanged, JTextField doesn't have it, but i NEED it:(
Thanks for asking;)

Comment: Use a `JTextField` and add a `DocumentListener`.

Comment: Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) - the GUI will 'freeze' when that happens. Instead of calling `Thread.sleep(n)` implement a Swing `Timer` for repeating tasks or a `SwingWorker` for long running tasks.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

That's because AWT and Swing are rendered in a different manner. It's not recommended mixing both AWT and Swing components.

You can learn more about it here:

http://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/~cs3283/ftp/Java/swingConnect/archive/tech_topics_arch/mixing/mixing.html

[Swing and AWT Mixing is bad, but still done, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12040131/swing-and-awt-mixing-is-bad-but-still-done-why)

[mixing awt and swing in GUI programming using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18918424/mixing-awt-and-swing-in-gui-programming-using-java)